# Iterator to reverse a for loop's order of execution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, python-itertools

I have been searching the docs for itertools, as well as SO for a while now and have not yet found what I'm looking for. I'm hoping to reverse the order of execution of a for loop so the following happens:

```
for letter in ["A","B","C"]:
    do_something(letter)
    do_something_else(letter)


def do_something(letter):
   print("do_something with " + letter)
 
def do_something_else(letter):
   print("do something_else with " + letter)
```

with the normal output of a for loop being:

```
do_something with A
do something_else with A
do_something with B
do something_else with B
do_something with C
do something_else with C
```

And I would like it (the iterator) to output like:

```
do_something with A
do_something with B
do_something with C
do something_else with A
do something_else with B
do something_else with C
```

I won't lie it's been a long day so the answer is probably right under my nose, the best I've come up with so far is:

```
for letter in ["A","B","C"]:
    do_something(letter)

for letter in ["A","B","C"]:
    do_something_else(letter)


def do_something(letter):
   print("do_something with " + letter)
 
def do_something_else(letter):
   print("do something_else with " + letter)
```

But that feels very clunky since I'm repeating the for loop. Any help is vastly appreciated. Thanks all!

Comment: Personally, I'd opt for `do_xyz(letters)` passing in the list and have each do_xyz function iterate over the list as needed.

Comment: I don't see anything "clunky" about iterating a collection twice when that's fundamentally what you want to do. Is there perhaps something specific to your problem that makes iterating twice undesirable?

Comment: It is simple, and definitely does what I want, but I always thought it was 'best practice' to not have repeating lines of code if you can avoid it. Maybe I'm overthinking it?

Comment: Since you can only iterate over an iterator once, you either have to create another one or save the items (temporarily) as they are encountered during the first pass, so they can be accessed again in the second pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is an outer loop over the functions, and an inner loop over the letters.

```
for f in [do_something, do_something_else]:
    for letter in ["A","B","C"]:
        f(letter)
```

Yet, another alternative is to use itertools/product on the functions an inputs (output is as desired).

```
from itertools import product

for f, letter in product([do_something, do_something_else], ["A","B","C"]):
    f(letter)
```

Comment: I'm using product() elsewhere in my code so this works great, Thank you! Marking as answered.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
results = [list(map(func,letters)) for func in [do_something,do_something_else]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`itertools.tee()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) function to make two independent letter iterators and the built-in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to "weave" the functions and letters together like so:

```
from itertools import tee


def do_something(letter):
   print("do_something with " + letter)

def do_something_else(letter):
   print("do something_else with " + letter)

for function, letters in zip((do_something, do_something_else), tee(["A","B","C"]) ):
    for letter in letters:
        function(letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the iteration twice:

```
for letter in ["A","B","C"]:
    do_something(letter)

for letter in ["A","B","C"]:
    do_something_else(letter)
```

Comment: That's exactly what the OP's current, allegedly undesirable, solution is.

Comment: Thank you! I actually have that exact code in my question, but it feels clunky to repeat the same loop twice, I'm hoping there is something better out there. If not, clunky it is!

Comment: Oh, I've just seen the edition. Another option will be keeping on a dictionary the results and after that, printing it on the order of the keys.

Comment: The above is just pseudocode, my actual functions are much more complex. I'm just getting the basic idea across so it's understood!

Comment: Yes, I got it but maybe, if you are doing some functions and you want to keep the results in that order, you can use collectors like lists or dictionaries to separate and sort your outputs. Like a bucket-sort.